# Joi date greater than now

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I am using Joi with express to validate the request. I need to validate the date field in the request body, so my code is next:

```
const dateSchema = Joi.date().greater(Date.now()).iso().required();
```

this works ok but the major problem is that `Date.now()` is picking up the date when I started an express server. So for example, if the server was started at 5:00, joi will not allow 4:59 but will allow everything that is greater than 5:00 even though the current time is 5:05.

How I can check `Joi.date().greater(dynamicDateNow)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [joi document](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#dategreaterdate) . You can use 'now' (string) value to compare with the current date time (when you execute validate)

```
const dateSchema = Joi.date().greater('now').iso().required();
```